# Function for drawing $\sin x$ with a maximum value of $360$ and minimum of $70$?

Tags: functions

I want a function to draw $\sin x$ between an upper limit of $360$ and a lower limit of $70$.

Attempt: I know how to handle the lower limit but I'm having trouble with the upper limit.

$$y = a(\sin(x)+1) + 70$$

Comment: The range of $\sin x$ is $[-1,1]$, which is a difference of $2$, so multiply that up to the desired range and then offset appropriately.

Comment: are you familiar with the techniques of single variable calculus? Simply take the derivative and solve for the zeros you want...  The constant should become clear

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin x$ goes from $-1$ to $+1$ you only need to make

$$f(x)=a\sin x+b$$ and solve the system $$\begin{cases}a+b=360\\-a+b=70\end{cases}$$ hence $$\color{red}{(a,b)=(145,215)}$$

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to find some shifted and scaled/stretched/compression version of $\sin x$ such that the upper limit is $360$ and the lower limit is $70$.

Then halfway between $y=360$ and $y=70$, we must have the midline of $y=215$. From $215$ we need to go up by an amplitude of $360-215=145$  to get to $360$ and down by $215-70=145$ to get to $70$. Hence, if we assume the point $(0,215)$, the equation your looking for is:

$$y=145\sin(x)+215$$

This follows from $-1 \leq \sin x \leq 1$, because then $145(1)+215$ will be our max and $145(-1)+215$ will be our minimum. You can add a horizontal stretch/compression if you wish.

If we have the more general point $(0,y(0))$ then using the same idea about the maximum value $\sin (u)$ to assume what you want is of the form:

$$y=145\sin(ax+b)+215$$

This assumption was made from begging (we want $\sin x$ stretched/compressed/shifted in such a way...). Anyways if you plug in $x=0$ you get:

$$c=145\sin(b)+215$$

You can solve for $b$. $a$ can be anything but if you don't want a horizontal stretch from our parent function $\sin x$, take $a=1$ because $a$ "scales" or stretches/ compresses your function in the horizontal direction.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out seconds after posting by luck. :)

$$y= \frac{290}{2}(\sin(x)+1)+70,$$

since $\sin (x)$ occupies a total height of $2$.

Comment: This does not work. The minimum is 70, but the maximum is $360+70=430$.

Comment: Indeed.  Replace $\frac{360}{2}$ with $\frac{290}{2}$ to fix the issue.